# Meaning of `x+" "+y` and `changeUs(x, y)`

Tags: java

I've got this code and i have got the answer for it as well, but I don't understand how they come out like that, specifically what does `(x+" "+y)` part means as well as the `changeUs(x, y)`, can anyone explain?

```
public class ChangeParam {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1;
        double y = 3.4;
        System.out.println(x+" "+y);
        changeUs(x, y);
        System.out.println(x+" "+y);        
    }

    public static void changeUs(int x, double y) {
        x = 0;
        y = 0.0;
        System.out.println(x +" "+y);
    }
}
```

The answers are:

```
1 3.4

0 0.0

1 3.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is logic, because **Java pass by value** and **not by reference**.

When you call `changeUs(x, y)` the the `x` and `y` will change only in the method, for that you get this result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 1;
    double y = 3.4;
    System.out.println(x+" "+y);//<<-------- 1- This will print 1 3.4
    changeUs(x, y);
    System.out.println(x+" "+y);//<<-------- 3- This will print 1 3.4        
}

public static void changeUs(int x, double y) {
    x = 0;
    y = 0.0;
    System.out.println(x +" "+y);//<<-------- 2- This will print 0 0.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read and study the Tutorial and the Java Language Specification. The semantics of operators such as `+` are among the first things explained. There you'll find that when either operand of `+` is of type `String` that the other operand is converted to a `String` via an implicit call to `String.valueOf`, making the whole expression a `String` concatenation.

Comment: well you see, I know how the + works, but the fact of the matter is that I have never seen anything like this that has x+ and then " , it was just a very confusing encouter for me @Lew Bloch

Comment: All right. But then you really don't know how `+` works. The operation works the same when either operand is a `String` reference; if the other operand is not a `String` then `String.valueOf` is applied to it. Both operands of `+` must be the same type, after conversion. Review the documentation for the operator.

Comment: Yeah, I believe the way I thought that I knew how it works was simply just a visual memory of how it looks, when I saw this I got confused, but if I would have actually learned it I would have been able to work this out myself. Thank you for the help regardless! :) @Lew Bloch

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` - here, println is a method which takes in a String type as argument (either a String, or a type which has been converted to a String). 
So , we pass a String. But, you've two things to display (x and y), how will you do that?
In java, `'+'` operator acts as a concatenation operator when operands are String type, so `x+" "+y` will combine 'x' and 'y' with a space in between.
So, if `x="HELLO"` and `y="WORLD"` , so `x+y` will be `HELLOWORLD`.

Giving a space in between, `x+" "+y` will give us a cleaner and more readable answer: `HELLO WORLD`

where as

```
changeUS()
```

is a method (specifically a static method) which takes in two parameters (much like a math function which needs two parameters).

So, we pass two "things" to the function. Now, how do I know the function needs two parameters? To know that I must know where the function is defined. As I see, the function is defined as:

```
public static void changeUs(int x, double y) {
x = 0;
y = 0.0;
System.out.println(x +" "+y);}
```

The first line: `enter code here:`public static void changeUs(int x, double y)`which says that changeUs takes`int and double` as their parameters.

So, pass an integer and a floating point number (double is a higher precision floating point number) . 

But, why did we do `System.out.println` but for `changeUs` we just called it without any of that prefixes? 
This is because `changeUs` is a 'static' method and doesn't need an object to operate upon.

Comment: thank you for getting this so in depth,  I am learning now more than I ever had, greatly appreciated @Rahul Bharadwaj

Comment: I'm sorry it doesn't allow me to upvote anything for some reason, and I won't be putting you as the correct answer because it has been explained earlier on, but you have gone indepth with it which is even more than I asked, if I would be able to give any other type of reputation I would :) @Rahul Bharadwaj

Comment: No Problem. 
The question you asked is really general and covers a lot of concepts. SO focuses on specific problems/ questions. So, start with basic Java tutorials. If you tackle problems, do thorough web searches before questioning on SO. 
It was also my mistake, one shouldn't be answering just for up votes and reputation!

Comment: You are right, I will start googling everything I can, thanks @Rahul Bharadwaj